# Jquery UI can't drag from left to right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, packery

On my page I'm using the `Jquery UI extension` to sort divs. The divs are arranged in 2 columns. I created a  [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/visozayuci/edit?html,css,output), please take a look on it.

When you drag all 3 divs to the left side, you can't get them on the right side again. Where is the mistake?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
    itemSelector: '.gridItem',
    gutter: '.gridGutter',
    percentPosition: true
  });

  var $items = $grid.find('.gridItem').draggable();
  $grid.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', $items);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.grid {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.gridItem {
  width: 49%;
  background-color: coral;
}
.gridGutter {
  width: 2%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2.1.1/dist/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridGutter"></div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 1</div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 2</div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will never be happy with jQuery UI :(

Comment: @DanielKobe should I use `Draggabilly`(http://draggabilly.desandro.com)?   I tried it first, but had the same issue.

Comment: Never used that before, but you can actually implement basic dragging functionality pretty easily, its a fun project imo. But my expereince with the jquery drag stuff was pretty crappy, you just gotta try messing with every option and possible way to do things but your gonna run into more issues if your porject gets more complicated. I dono what packery does? Why not try mimicking the examples from the docs? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Comment: @DanielKobe `Packery is a JavaScript library and jQuery plugin that makes gapless and draggable layouts.`. My first thought was to do the dragging functionality by myself. I will do it definitely, but not in this project. Anyways, thanks for the comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Packery documentation says](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html#grid-drop-positions) the following:

> Without columnWidth set, dragged items can only be dropped in place of other items.

You [can set a selector](http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#columnwidth) for the `columnWidth` so it takes that element's width as the column's width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
    itemSelector: '.gridItem',
    gutter: '.gridGutter',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.gridSizer'
  });

  var $items = $grid.find('.gridItem').draggable();
  $grid.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', $items);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.grid {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.gridSizer,
.gridItem {
  width: 49%;
}
.gridItem {
  background-color: coral;
}
.gridGutter {
  width: 2%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2.1.1/dist/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridSizer"></div>
  <div class="gridGutter"></div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 1</div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 2</div>
  <div class="gridItem">div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't saw this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a columnWidth: 390 as show below it should work.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
            itemSelector: '.gridItem',
            gutter: '.gridGutter',
            columnWidth: 390,
            percentPosition: true
          });

          var $items = $grid.find('.gridItem').draggable();
          $grid.packery( 'bindUIDraggableEvents', $items );
        });
```

I suspect that when you move all div to the left it sees it as only one column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't saw it!